# Laravel Lumen Memcached not found

Tags: php, laravel, memcached, lumen

Ok, I just started with Lumen and I'm trying to use the Auth, but a call to either Auth::check or any other function of Auth.. leads to the below Error
**Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in   vendor\illuminate\cache\MemcachedConnector.php on line 52**.
I don't want to use Memcached never used it before.

I disabled it in the **.env** file and set the **CACHE_DRIVER** and **SESSION_DRIVER** to array, but still shows the same error.

I decided not to use Auth again and to manually handle my authetication with sessions/tokens, but enabling the MiddleWare StartSession results to the same error.

```
$app->middleware([
 // 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
 // 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
  'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
 // 'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
 // 'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
]);
```

Please I'd be so glad if anyone can really help me out here

**EDIT**

After going A little Deep in the framework
I Hard Coded the session driver name in the `SessionManager` Class
within the method `getSessionConfig`

```
public function getSessionConfig()
{
    $this->setDefaultDriver("cookie");//I added this line
    return $this->app['config']['session'];
}
```

It works though but not a good way of doing things.
There is no config file, i believe all configurations are written in **.env** file, but i really don't know why the session_driver and cache_driver is defaulted to memecached even after changing it in the **.env** and then ran `composer dump-autoload` ... Lumen :(

**EDIT**
This is my **.env** file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomKey!!!

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

I already have this line uncommented in my bootsrap/app.php

```
 Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
```

My DataBase configuration works perfectly so the .env file is loaded
quite alright.

Comment: Sorry did you already follow the documentations steps ? http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/authentication

Comment: and the cache docs ? http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/cache

Comment: could you insert your .env file please?

Comment: @lorenz i stated it clearly that i don't want to use memcache, so i really don't know how it answered my question + i don't have enough reputation to downvote you, im sorry twasn't me.

Comment: @borraciaBlu trust me i have gone through the documentation.. Please see the edited question

Comment: Are you certain this is the correct .env file?

Comment: There are two, .env and .env.example, what i use for my db connection is .env and it works. even on the .env.example i placed the same settings just to test, but no luck

Comment: Somewhere in your code do `env('SESSION_DRIVER')` and see what it returns... (Oh and also please answer with `@lukasgeiter` so I get a notification ;))

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks for the reply... I'm sorta confuse env('SESSION_DRIVER') returns memcached even when its set to cookie in my .env file.

Comment: @PaulOkeke Hmmm. Can you comment out the Dotenv::load and then try the same again?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Still the same result, It returns memcached. :(

Comment: @PaulOkeke That means either for some reason this is set for your environment (and not overridden correctly) or your somehow working with the wrong file(s) Can you tell me a bit about your setup?

Comment: You may need to restart your server, especially if you're using `php artisan serve`.

I had exactly the same issue - trying to use file cache, but received errors regarding Memcached - restarting the server reloads the .env. Doesn't appear to pick up changes per-request.

Comment: @AlexOsborn ... Yayyy!!! Yay!!!! It Worked.....I shut down and then restarted the server. i mostly do hibernate my system so i don't restart things all the time... Thanks much

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks for helping as well... Thanks Y' all

Comment: Of course!!! (Y) @AlexOsborn Please answer the question so the solution is more visible to others and the question marked as solved :)

Comment: Remember to rename .env.example => .env after installing. that was my problem :$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may need to restart your server, especially if you're using `php artisan serve`.

Lumen doesn't appear to pick up `.env` changes per-request.

I had exactly the same issue - trying to use file cache, but received errors regarding Memcached - restarting the server reloads the `.env` file.

Answer (score 46):

I spent 3 hours on this problem today. With the help of [the post of demve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128239/3452348) in this topic, I found the solution. Very simple! I hope it won't affect me later in my development.

Just to it, in the **`.env`** file :

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=array
```

Ok, I make an **UPDATE** because I was faced with a new problem about the session. In fact, when you set the previous parameters, your session won't be persistent, like said in the [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/session#session-drivers): `array - sessions will be stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.`

So I have to change it, always in **`.env`** a file like that :

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

With a `var_dump(Session::all());` I now can see the whole values of my session

Comment: The term 'solution' is misleading. This is a workaround. You didn't fix memcached, you just use something else.

Answer (score 14):

This issue resolved when i installed this package so try at least

First i tried this and it works fine

```
CACHE_DRIVER = array
```

but then thought about what is `memcached`

Then i tried this and it works fine without changing driver `memcached`

```
apt-get install php-memcached
```

yum package manager or in Amazon Linux.

```
yum install php-memcached -y
```

Comment: This indeed should be the best answer, while all other answers are just work-around by using another cache driver.

P.S. use `yum install php-memcached -y` in Amazon Linux

Comment: wow, this happened to me right after doing an apt install upgrade and it turns out that the memcached from php7.3 had been uninstalled for some unknown reason. I tried this solution and recovered the site

Answer (score 8):

In .env file replace

```
#This line:- 
  CACHE_DRIVER = memcached

#With this:- 
   CACHE_DRIVER = array
```

Comment: and you can still use memcache ?

Comment: @user269867 no please comment #CACHE_DRIVER = memcached

Comment: This worked for me in the context of "I am just trying to get Lumen going for the first time."

Answer (score 7):

Make sure not to get caught out by your .env file not being loaded, which by default it's commented out in Lumen. So if you are specifying a different cache driver in your .env, do the following.

> Note: If you are using the .env file to configure your application, don't forget to uncomment the Dotenv::load() method in your bootstrap/app.php file.

Source: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/cache

Answer (score 4):

in your `.env` file, you can also use `CACHE_DRIVER=file` instead of `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached`

Comment: This worked for me! I'm in a shared hosting environment and restarting is not an option. :D

Answer (score 2):

In my case i added Add `CACHE_DRIVER=array` in .env file
Then

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
```

in my `bootstrap/app.php` and the `.env` file started working.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that I used the php-7 branch of homestead repository which does not have PHP memcached ready.

Comment: Yeah, this happened to me. You'll have to install the php7 branch of memcached: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073141/has-anyone-got-memcached-to-work-on-laravel-homestead-php7-box

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem now, I couldn't track it down but my guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the defaults configurations are stored in the `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config` folder, the `DotEnv::$inmutable` setting and the `artisan serve`server.

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Add in **`bootstrap/app.php`** the following:
   `Dotenv::makeMutable();
   Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
   Dotenv::makeImmutable();`
2. in the **`.env`** file, set all the configuration to "basic drivers" (array, file) even if you are not going to use them, because you w

Comment: This seems to work in Lumen 5.2! Can you provide additional info for this solution? Why does this work? What does makeMuteable() do?

Comment: MakeMutable set the Dotenv object to override its previous values.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a new lumen installation, 
you must rename `.env.example` to `.env` . So it can read your configurations!

Comment: Well i dont want to argue with you. Yes i am a newbie and integrate the lumen with the  swagger and twinfield. Its not the solution you give i already read in doc.

Comment: this is an answer as it worked for me. - easy to forgot to do this.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if your .env file is owned by another user than the one trying to run the artisan command.

Answer (score -2):

Check if `memcached` is installed, if not install it by running:

```
apt-get install php5-memcached
```