# Has anyone got memcached to work on Laravel Homestead php7 box?

Tags: laravel, memcached, laravel-5.1, homestead, php-7

I loaded up Laravel/Lumen on the new Homestead php7 box and encountered this error:

```
FatalThrowableError in MemcachedConnector.php line 51:
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found
```

Doing a `phpinfo();` shows there is no memcached extension, but `sudo service memcached status` says memcached is running. It seems there is a php7 branch for memcached here: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/tree/php7

Can anyone guide me on how to get it working in the new php7 Homestead VM?

EDIT: I just saw on the [homestead install documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) that it says "Memcached (PHP 5.x Only)". Question still remains on how to get it working.

Comment: It's now working on Forge, which is awesome

Comment: Memcached (ending in a 'd') works for me on Laravel 5.4 Homestead on Windows 10 when I do a very basic test. However, certain key/values are failing to save, and I haven't figured out the cause yet.

Comment: Ahh, the reason only my basic test was working and not my more complicated cases was because I misunderstood how tags work. I didn't know that I needed to specify tags during a `get` as well (and I still don't really understand why).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work on php-memcached for PHP7 is not yet complete, not all tests pass; You can use everything but JSON serialization, I think.

There is no pecl support for PHP7, so right now you need to install extensions manually, like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached
cd php-memcached
git checkout php7
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You must make sure that `phpize` is the PHP7 version. Additionally, if the `php` in your PATH is not PHP7, then the `php-config` in your PATH is not either, in this case you must pass `--with-php-config=/absolute/path/to/php7-config` to `./configure`.

Comment: Does this require `build-essential` (gcc) and/or `php7-dev` packages as well?

Comment: @fideloper : I had to install `php7.0-dev` and `libmemcached-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but on Windows when using `XAMPP`. It seems `memcached` works for now with PHP 5+ only.

The problem for Windows users is to find the right .dll file named 
`php_memcache.dll` (x86/x64 platforms).

I've spent hours looking for a solution, but nothing found. The very fresh description how to use `memcached` is here:

[HOW TO: Install Memcache on XAMPP (Windows 7/8/10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173231/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp-windows-7-8-10)

We still have to wait for PHP7+ implementation.