# HOW TO: Install Memcache on XAMPP (Windows 7/8/10)

Tags: php, laravel-5, memcached

I am doing a project on Laravel. I'm trying to make a simple system that uses cache focused on memcache. When I started studying, I checked Laravel site first and then I found that using the Memcached cache requires the Memcached PECL package to be installed.

I searched through it and I got some problems during installation.

How to install `memcache`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are the steps that should be followed when you install memcache.

1. Start your xampp.
2. Click on 'config' and open php.ini file.

search for

`;extension=php_memcache.dll`

If not found add

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211
```

3. Download the file `php_memcache.dll` from [windows.php.net](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache)
   (**make sure to check your php version and php_memcache.dll are same. Otherwise, it will through error.**)

unzip it and paste '.dll' file in the path **xampp\php\ext**, in my case it is **F:\xampp\php\ext** (I had to rename the file to ***memcache.dll***  but when you take a look on other sites that describes the steps for this, they don't tell to rename, but I have done this in my project!).

4. Download and install Memcache server for windows

Download the **Memcache.exe** from [jellycan](http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip)

After completion of download, unzip and put the **memcache.exe** file into any desired directory of your choice (e.g. C:/memcached/). make sure folder name should be **memcached**

5. Open the **cmd prompt** with **“Run as Administrator”** and execute the line to install

`c:/memcached/memcached.exe -d install`

then type

`net start "memcached server"`

In case you get memcache is already installed. then just go through  line `net start "memcached server"`.

**Or**

For the installation purpose you can go to the path where you have copied the *memcache.exe*. and double click to the file, memcache is installed, now just add line `net start "memcached server"` and your memcache is enabled.

6. Restart Xampp Apache
7. Restart Memcached:

   `C:\Windows\system32> net start “memcached”`

   *The memcached service is starting.
   The memcached service was started successfully.*

   `C:\Windows\system32> net stop  “memcached”`

   *The memcached service is stopping.
   The memcached service was stopped successfully.*

Comment: `net start "memcached server"` throws an error, but without quotes doesn't `net start memcached server`, and it works.

Comment: And how do I check now if I installed it correctly ? Shall I see it in phpinfo() log ? Because it is not there. And I`m a bit confused. Do I need to install memcached on the windows or only on the xampp localhost ?

Comment: error when run `memcache.exe -d install `    "Failed to ignore SIGHUP: No error"

Comment: For me on PHP 7.3 , I was stuck after doing all steps , then just replace extension=php_memcache.dll with extension=memcache as per standards libraries included. It worked for me.

Comment: i got this error `MemcachePool::set(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache\r\n` is there anybody now how to configure its default max size?