# Memcached implementation in php rise error

Tags: php, memcached

I am new in php Memcached. I am trying to implement memcached for my application handling thousand of request. But while initialize Memcached class on scripts as follow:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 
$mc = new Memcached();
```

Then I am getting following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mamecache.php on line 4

I am new on this technologies, why I am getting this please let know?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you haven't installed memcached on your pc that's why you are getting error.

Please check following post:

[HOW TO: Install Memcache on XAMPP (Windows 7/8/10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173231/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp-windows-7-8-10)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install memcached for php first.

try `sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql php5 php5-memcached memcached`

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: OP is using windows though. https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows looks legit