# Unable to Install memcached on xampp

Tags: php, memcached

I am installing memcached on xampp on windows with php 5.6.33. It's showing message memcached server installed and started successfully in cmd, But memcached is not showing in phpInfo. Also when running php, it shows Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found.

Comment: First of all, this belongs on another part of stackoverflow (serverfault.com). But did you enable the library in your php.ini

Comment: You need to configure php.ini library. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173231/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp-windows-7-8-10) link for more details.

Comment: Yes, I have already added these lines to php.ini. I have taken reference from the same link while installing.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found) link as well, cause @RanjanKumar you are installing **memcached** and fatal error is related to **Memcache**.

Comment: Ok, but memcached also not showing in phpInfo. Also Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found. But memcached server is started.