# Configuring memcached using Docker with php7.4

Tags: php, docker, mysqli, docker-compose, php-7

I am new to docker i am trying to configure the memcache using docker its not working for me.

my doccker.yml file

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/${PHPVERSION}
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${PHPVERSION}'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links: 
      - database
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT-/var/www/html}
      PMA_PORT: ${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  database:
    build:
      context: "./bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-database'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
  redis:
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

i have search on internet and try too many things but dint work for me. my Docker file is empty currently. currently i am using php7.4 with mysql 5

Comment: "doesn't work" means very little. What's not working? Do you receive errors? What kind of errors?

Comment: no error its only not installing

Comment: Questions about server configuration are off-topic here, and are better suited for [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear but i am sharing some details. I hope it will work for you. the file name must be Dockerfile and add the following code to it.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build- 
essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev
RUN pecl install memcached-2.2.0
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

after that run the build
OR
you are using xampp please fellow the [HOW TO: Install Memcache on XAMPP (Windows 7/8/10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173231/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp-windows-7-8-10)

Comment: thank you my Dockerfile name was incorrect