# Class "Memcached" not found on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, memcached, lumen

I am faced with this problem when I run any artisan commands on Heroku. Its a Lumen-PHP Project. I have added the "ext-memcached" to the require section of the composer.json but still gets the same result.

[Screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdFG5.png)

Comment: You might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788552/laravel-lumen-memcached-not-found

Comment: @OlubodunAgbalaya Thanks for taking time out to answer. I finally got my head around it. See solution below

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my hands around this and thanks to the [Heroku Docs on Memcached](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier#php). I quote Heroku Docs:

> The php-memcached client is not a pure PHP client but a PECL extention that makes use of libmemcached. You thus need to install php-memcached via your OS package manager.

Make sure you have Memcached Installed on your local machine. You can check a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gofaniyi/0ad69c00f6817b28bc86098661d65a3f) I created on how to do this for Mac OSx. I will post it here anyways.

```
brew install libevent
brew install autoconf
brew install libmemcached

//go to
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php{{VERSION}}/bin

//compile memcached
./pecl install memcached

//go back
cd ../

//Add the memcached.so extension to your php.ini file
echo -e "\n[memcached]\nextension=memcached.so" >> conf/php.ini

//start memcached server
memcached -m 24 -p 11211 -d

//restart MAMPP
```

You’ll need to modify your composer.json file to include the module:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "ext-memcached": "*"
  }
}
```

Ensure that your new requirements are “frozen” to composer.lock by running:

```
composer update
```

Afterwards, commit your changes and run

```
git push heroku master
```

Thats it!!